# undefined method `whiteboards_path' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and trying to create a new page with a form, fairly simple, but it keeps coming back with this error (listed below) on the `<%= form_for @whiteboard do |f| %>`line. I've looked at similar posts where people are having the same issue as me but none of the solutions seem to work for me. Would greatly appreciate some help, thanks!

Error Message:

```
NoMethodError in Whiteboard#new

undefined method `whiteboards_path' for #<#<Class:0x37014d8>:0x36b2d10>
Did you mean?  whiteboard_path

<%= form_for @whiteboard do |f| %>
  <div>
      <% f.label :title %>
      <% f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
```

My Controller:

```
class WhiteboardController < ApplicationController

def index
    @whiteboards = Whiteboard.all;
end

def show
  @whiteboard = Whiteboard.find(params[:id])
end

def new 
  @whiteboard = Whiteboard.new
end

end
```

My View (whiteboard/new.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for @whiteboard do |f| %>
    <div>
        <% f.label :title %>
        <% f.text_field :title %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <% f.label :description %>
        <% f.text_field :description %>
    </div>

    <div>
        <% f.submit :title %>
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'home#index'

  resources :whiteboard

  get 'whiteboard/wbpage'

  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/info'

  devise_for :users
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple pluralization error.

```
resources :whiteboards
```

In Rails `resources` should always be plural. On the rare occasion that you have a real [singular resource](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) you should use `resource` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of pluralization so my controller name needed to be changed.

Comment: Yeah, routes, controllers and tables are plural. Models are singular.

Answer (score 0):

**My Suggestion please mind  it**

- when you create controller use pluralization
- when you create Model  use Singular (first letter must be camel case)

***For Example***

```
rails g controller articles 
rails g model Article
```

Comment: Actually the case does not matter when you run the generators, unless you are using compound words where you can use either snake case or camel case.